# Unable to start service [service name] with null

Tags: android, android-widget, nullpointerexception, android-service

i recently coded a Android Widget and tested it on Emulator as well as my Galaxy S , it worked fine on both, after i posted the same to android market now i am getting some error reports.

i am stating a service in the onUpdate of Widget Class like this:

```
if (appWidgetIds != null) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to
    // this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // Start Service for each instance
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Intent active = new Intent(context, DialerService.class);
        active.setAction("Start");
        active.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                appWidgetId);

        context.startService(active);
    }
}
```

the error which some people are getting is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service dialer.impact.DialerService@45f926f0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3282)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2211)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
**at dialer.impact.DialerService.onStart(DialerService.java:18)**
at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:420)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3267)
... 10 more
```

error states a `NullPointerException` on line 18 of the `ServiceClass` which is this:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    //Line 18th 
            String command = intent.getAction();
    int appWidgetId = intent.getExtras().getInt(
            AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
    RemoteViews remoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
}
```

Line 18 is the `String command = intent.getAction();`

what could be the reason for intent being null 
please help

Answer (score 31, accepted):

According to the documentation for [`onStart()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStart(android.content.Intent,%20int)) (actually `onStartCommand()` but the parameters are the same):

> *intent*  The Intent supplied to startService(Intent), as given. **This may be null** if the service is being
>   restarted after its process has gone
>   away, and it had previously returned
>   anything except
>   START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it, i think its the Task Killer apps which people use might be killing the service

Comment: so how to handle when service is being restart? it always make error

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this. I am getting the same issues with Google Analytics in my app.

Answer (score 4):

Hi just to add on to this, so the workaround is just to add a if(intent!=null) before the getAction()? If I do this, will the service start up properly later on it's own? Meaning the OS actually helps me start the service properly in the case of a null intent. I'm afraid of ending up in a situation where the service doesn't get started at all.

Comment: Yes you should be fine if you put null check for intent

Comment: if you check for the null value then, it will not throw any exception on that check..